# How to avoid CannotSerializeTransactionException when using Spring with Postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I'm trying to understand how to manage transactions in Spring Boot with backing PostgreSQL DBMS. Here is a small repository, whose `sell()` method checks to see whether there is enough coffee in stock, and if so - updates `coffees` and `sales` table accordingly. I annotated the method with `@Transactional` to guarantee that no two or more simultaneous method invocations would accidentally sell more quantity than there is in stock. Also, it's needed for updating two tables atomically.

However, the code below doesn't work as I expected when simulating two parallel transactions. Instead of suspending the second transaction and waiting for the completion of the first one, it throws **CannotSerializeTransactionException**, so that the second transaction always fails - whether there is enough coffee in stock or not.

```java
@Repository
public class CoffeesRepositoryImpl implements CoffeesRepository {
    
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Autowired
    public CoffeesRepositoryImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbc) {
        this.jdbc = jdbc;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void sell(int coffeeId, int saleQuantity, String manager) {

        // step #1: check if we have enough coffee in stock
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM coffees WHERE id = ?";
        Coffee coffee = jdbc.queryForObject(sql, this::mapRowToCoffeeObject, coffeeId);
        int stockAfterSale = coffee.getStock() - saleQuantity;
        if (stockAfterSale < 0)
            throw new RuntimeException("Attempt to sell more quantity then there is in stock");

        // step #2: update coffee stock after sale
        sql = "UPDATE coffees SET stock = ? WHERE id = ? ";
        jdbc.update(sql, stockAfterSale, coffeeId);

        // note: this sleep is used while testing to help 
        // simulate situation with two simultaneous calls 
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // step #3: insert new record into sales table
        sql = "INSERT INTO sales (coffee_id, manager, datetime, sale_quantity, sale_sum) " +
                "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        BigDecimal saleSum = coffee.getPrice().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(saleQuantity));
        jdbc.update(sql, coffeeId, manager, LocalDateTime.now(), saleQuantity, saleSum);
    }

    private Coffee mapRowToCoffeeObject(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return new Coffee(rs.getInt("id"),
                rs.getString("name"),
                rs.getBigDecimal("price"),
                rs.getInt("stock"));
    }

}
```

This is the contents of my `coffees` table before and after two transactions:

```
id  name    price   stock
1   Arusha  15.90   9000
2   Catuai  18.00   10000
3   Mocha   17.00   7200
```

- request #1: coffeesRepository.sell(2, 2000, 'admin')
- request #2: coffeesRepository.sell(2, 500, 'admin')

```
id  name    price   stock
1   Arusha  15.90   9000
2   Catuai  18.00   8000
3   Mocha   17.00   7200
```

And in the sales table only one record is inserted
with sale quantity 2000 and sale sum 36 000,00.

Although the second request would seemingly have all chances to finish the transaction with success after suspension, it just throws `CannotSerializeTransactionException` instead.

Comment: Problem is with your `Transaction Isolation` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html

Comment: @Thirumal, thank you. The referred documentation clearly says : _"Applications using this level must be prepared to retry transactions due to serialization failures."_

Comment: As a possible solution, I decided to change the isolation level to `READ_COMMITTED`, then replace the first `SELECT` with `SELECT... FOR UPDATE` and probably make 'coffees' table `UPDATE` the final step in the transaction, thus swapping step #2 with step #3.